# Can't See the List of Multi-Vlan-Firewalls in Softlayer via Softlayer Rest Api

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Hi i am trying to List the Multi-Vlan-Firewalls present in my account using the softlayer rest api. On the softlayer ui i can see the list of Multi-Vlan-Firewall but i can't see the same thing using softlayer rest api. The rest api i tried using to see the list is

`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[id,name,vlanNumber,networkSpace,note,primaryRouter[id,hostname,datacenter[id,name,longName]],networkVlanFirewall[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName],attachedNetworkGateway[id,name],attachedNetworkGatewayVlan[bypassFlag],billingItem[id,cancellationDate],type,firewallNetworkComponentCount,firewallGuestNetworkComponentCount]`.

All the details that were sent back belonged to single-vlan-firewall. I even tried to see the list of Multi-vlan-Firewalls in my account using the slcli(Softlayer command line interface). I got a list of firewalls but they were all single vlan-firewalls. Am i missing something? Can anyone please tell me which api to use to list Multi-vlan-Firewalls in Softlayer. I even tried to see in inspect mode of chrome what api is the Softlayer UI using to fetch the list of Multi-Vlan-Firewall? I got something like this https://control.softlayer.com/security/firewalls/getmultivlanlist . This is the rest api Softlayer UI is using to fetch the list of Multi-Vlan-Firewall. And in response to this i get the list of firewalls as

```
{name: "Checkdelete1", id: 13573, firewallType: "FortiGate Security Appliance",…}
associatedVlan
:
"0 VLANs"
configuration
:
"HA"
firewallType
:
"FortiGate Security Appliance"
id
:
13573
location
:
"dal13.pod01"
name
:
"Checkdelete1"
status
:
"Active"
```

I tried to correlate this id with the the rest api that i was using earlier to fetch the list of firewall. I couldn't find this id anywhere in that response. And hence i concluded that maybe i am using the wrong api to fetch the list of Multi-Vlan-Firewalls or softlayer doesn't respond with the Multi-Vlan-Firewalls in that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the request:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways?objectMask=mask[id,name,networkFirewall[id,customerManagedFlag,datacenter.name],publicIpAddress.ipAddress,publicVlan[id,primaryRouter.hostname],privateIpAddress.ipAddress,insideVlans[id],memberCount,status.keyName]
```

but the control portal filters the data fetched by the request above, you need consider only the objects which has the "NetworkFirewall" property e.g.

```
{
        "id": 1111,
        "name": "Provisioning",
        "memberCount": 1,
        "insideVlans": [],
        "networkFirewall": {
            "customerManagedFlag": true,
            "id": 11222,
            "datacenter": {
                "name": "dal10"
            }
        },
        "privateIpAddress": {
            "ipAddress": "10.11.11.111"
        },
        "publicIpAddress": {
            "ipAddress": "169.22.22.2222"
        },
        "publicVlan": {
            "id": 11111,
            "primaryRouter": {
                "hostname": "fcr01a.dal10"
            }
        },
        "status": {
            "keyName": "UPDATING"
        }
    },
```

Comment: if the answer helped you please mark it as the right answer

Comment: I also need to know the type of the device it is ie. Fortigate Security Appliance or anything else. I dont get this from the api u mentioned. Can u please tell me which object mask to use to get this

Comment: please create a new question for this